# How to get cakephp to reduce the size of HTTP Post response?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have used cakephp's cake bake facility to quickly build a simple website. My application involves plenty of HTTP POST to add records to the database. However, it is not as fast as I like and the web host provider has a quota for network traffic.

I am using python request module to send the HTTP POST. I noticed that the HTTP response from cakephp is quite a lot. How to get cakephp to reduce the size of its HTTP Post response? I don't really care about the response.

I am using cakephp 2.3

Comment: Try to compress response in web server with gzip, or if it's apache with `mod_deflate`

Comment: Can you post a sample response, and elaborate more on why it's not needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$this->response->statusCode(204);
return $this->response;

will send a response without any content and statuscode 204, meaning the resource was created

Comment: I tried it. For some reason, the default is always statuscode 500. Do I have to do anything with CakeResponse? Sorry, I am still a newbie to cakephp.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#CakeResponse

Comment: Now, it works. The problem with the status 500 was that there was a missing view.ctp. I wish I could vote up your answer but my reputation points are too low. Sorry about that.